# Java JOptionPane text bugged to unreadable levels?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane, parseint

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o08Nn.jpg

[image]

Here's a picture of what it ends up looking like, I don't think it's a problem with the code as it's copied straight from the tutorial website. I've reinstalled JDK, as well as run it in command line and Eclipse. Any possibilities?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Swag {

    public static void main ( String[] args) {

        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How old are you?");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(input);

        System.out.print(" Hello, " +name);
        System.out.println("Next year you'll be " +(age+1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code would still help reproduce and investigate.

Comment: Sorry I didn't really think it was a problem with the code, but it's in there now

Comment: It might be a problem with graphics card, altough I also experience this issue with internet explorer. But this has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Yeah I kinda figured it wasn't anything to do with the code, how could I fix the problem with my graphics card?

Comment: *"I don't think it's a problem with the code as it's copied straight from the tutorial website."*  URL of this 'tutorial site'?  Note that that code shown already has at least one grievous problem.  Stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows 7.
I had a similar problem today, and disabling ClearType fixed the problem.
Try to search "ClearType" in your control panel and disable it on all your monitors.
But it seems that this problem can happen in different situations..